# Intertwined shape in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I would like to re-create the following shape in Illustrator CC.

[image: shape]

Can someone please tell me how it can be done? I tried messing about with two circles, but couldn't get them to stop being circles :/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. Create a six pointed star, and modify using Live Corners.

[image]

2. *Object > Expand* then add new fill and stroke

[image]

3. Ungroup the shape, and remove the centre line path that's left over.
4. *Edit > Copy*
5. *Edit > Paste in Place*
6. *Object > Transform > Rotate*, enter 30 degrees, and rotate
7. Select All (CTRL+A)
8. Select the Shape builder tool, and carefully merge the shapes so that one goes over, and one goes under the other.

[image]

Comment: how would you add the little cut out where they overlap? If you look at the original image, you'll notice there's a space when the path goes over another

Comment: @Ciwan I can't think of an automatic way to do that, but you could draw a little shape to use to make a cutout from each shape, copy and paste it, rotate -30 degrees, repeat for each shape, and then use the Pathfinder Minus Front operation to cut one shape from the other. [See short video here](https://imgur.com/a/zDRkp). It's a little tedious.

Comment: It would be faster to just do one segment then rotate copies.

Comment: @BillyKerr in your short vide, I noticed that the small shape you've created has a concave edge, how did you do that? My shape is just a rectangle, and it doesn't look good :(

Comment: @Ciwan I made it with the Pen Tool, and created the curve.

Comment: @joojaa, it's certainly possible with a transform rotation effect in the appearance panel, but I think that setting it up woudn't be quite so easy, which is why I avoided it.

Comment: you dont need rotation effect just rotation once with rotation tool and repeat last transform. Which should be familliar to any illustrator user.

Comment: I was bored, so I added in shadows to the shape [see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/chbo2.png)

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use star tool to do this.

Here's an example how you can do this with the help of star tool.

[image]

Comment: How did you get to the 2nd step from a regular star?

Comment: Yes, Use direct selection tool to select anchor points and round it

Comment: Thanks, but what about the "intertwined" effect, if you notice, you'll see there a looping effect (the path is cut where they touch)

Comment: several ways to do it. you can it manually..